# full visualisation of draft genomes alignment

Tags: sequence-alignment, genome, software-recommendation, visualization

I have two draft genomes (aprox. 500Mb each), one with ~10'000 scaffolds (`genome1.fasta`) and one with ~1'000 contigs (`genome2.fasta`). I would like to visualize their pairwise alignment, which [a while ago](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/visualisation-of-genome-alignment) I found it could easily be done by [mummerplot](http://mummer.sourceforge.net/manual/#mummerplot) in [MUMmer](http://mummer.sourceforge.net/).

In mummer, [pairwise draft genomes alignment](http://mummer.sourceforge.net/manual/#aligningdraft) is supported:

> Many times it is necessary to align two genomes that have not yet been completed, or two genomes with multiple chromosomes. This can make things a little more complicated, since a separate alignment would have to be generated for each possible pairing of the sequences. However, both NUCmer and PROmer automate this process and accept multi-FastA inputs, thus simplifying the process of aligning two sets of contigs, scaffolds or chromosomes.

It is still ok if I do it aligning small portions (e.g. contig vs scaffold), as I could get [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/4155/294). However, if I do it all-vs-all, I end up with a "confetti"-plot (self-coined term) instead of a dot-plot :

[image]

I am not sure how to interpret this, and what I would like to see is more of a straight line as the one. Probably it's just a matter of filtering, so I'd like to ask for advice.

I used [nucmer](http://mummer.sourceforge.net/manual/#nucmer) through [delta-filter](http://mummer.sourceforge.net/manual/#filter) as follows:

```
# mummer version //4.0.0beta1 

# nucmer
nucmer --prefix=ref_qry genome1.fasta genome2.fasta

# ref_qry.delta generated from previous step
delta-filter -r -q ref_qry.delta > ref_qry.filter

# plot
mummerplot ref_qry.filter -R genome1.fasta -Q genome2.fasta --filter --layout
```

Reasons for options `-r -q` in `delta-filter` step :

> To determine a one-to-one mapping of each reference and query, combine the options and use delta-filter -r -q.

I'll also accept other methods for visualisation (doesn't need to be withh MUMmer). Any input is greatly appreciated!

---

*EDIT*

I found some solutions which I reported as answers. I will accept anyone giving answer on how to tune MUMmer parameters to achieve the goal I describe in the original question.

Comment: http://dgenies.toulouse.inra.fr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution, using [D-Genies](http://dgenies.toulouse.inra.fr/), worked great.

Some examples from their website:

[image]

Thanks to [@user172818](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/users/37/user172818).

Answer (score 1):

Also, [Mashmap](https://github.com/marbl/MashMap) has an embedded [visualisation tool](https://github.com/marbl/MashMap#visualize) generating dot-plots to visualize mappings, ideal for:

- highly similar species or to compare different assemblies of the same species.
- mapping genome assembly or long reads (PacBio/ONT) to reference genome

An example from their website:

[image]